# xarray discrete scatter plot: specifying legend/colour order

Tags: python, scatter-plot, python-xarray, discrete

Plotting a discrete `xarray` `DataArray` variable in a `Dataset` with `xr.plot.scatter()` yields a legend in which the discrete values are ordered arbitrarily, corresponding to unpredictable colour assignment to each level. Would it be possible to specify a specific colour or position for a given discrete value?

A simple reproducible example:

```
import xarray as xr

# get a predefined dataset
uvz = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("eraint_uvz")

# select a 2-D subset of the data
uvzr = uvz.isel(level=0, month=0, latitude=slice(150, 242),
                longitude=slice(240, 300))

# define a discrete variable based on levels of a continuous variable
uvzr['zone'] = 'A'
uvzr['zone'] = uvzr.zone.where(uvzr.u > 30, other='C')
uvzr['zone'] = uvzr.zone.where(uvzr.u > 10, other='B')

# do the plot
xr.plot.scatter(uvzr, x='longitude', y='latitude', hue='zone')
```

[image: This produces the following plot]

Is there a way to ensure that the legend entries are arranged 'A', 'B', 'C' from top to bottom, say? Or ensure that A is assigned to blue, and B to orange, for example?

I know I can reset the values of the `matplotlib` color cycler, but for that to be useful I first need to know which order the discrete values will be plotted in.

I'm using `xarray v2022.3.0` on python 3.8.6. With an earlier version of xarray (I think 0.16) the levels were arranged alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ugly workaround using `xarray.Dataset.stack` and `xr.where(..., drop=True)`, in case anyone else is stuck with a similar problem.

```
import numpy as np   # for unique, to cycle through values
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   # to get a legend

# instead of np.unique you could pass an iterable of your choice
# specifying the order
for value in np.unique(uvzr.zone):
    # convert to a 1-D dataframe with a co-ordinate including all
    # unique combinations of latitude-longitude values
    uvzr_stacked = uvzr.stack({'location':('longitude', 'latitude')})

    # now select only those grid points in zone value
    uvzr_stacked = uvzr_stacked.where(uvzr_stacked.zone == value,
                                      drop=True)

    # the plotting function can't see the original dims any more;
    # a new name is required, however
    uvzr_stacked['lat'] = uvzr_stacked.latitude
    uvzr_stacked['lon'] = uvzr_stacked.longitude

    # plot!
    xr.plot.scatter(uvzr_stacked, x='lon', y='lat', hue='zone',
                    add_guide=False)

plt.legend(title='zone')
```

Comment: I would still really appreciate any suggestions of a better solution!